# Hive 2.3.2 Local Mode Cannot Find Hadoop Installation

Tags: hadoop, hive

According to what I've been reading, you can run Hive without Hadoop or HDFS (like in cases of using Spark or Tez), i.e. in local mode by setting the `fs.default.name` and `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` to local paths. However, when I do this, I get an error:

```
Starting Hive metastore service.
Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path
```

My hive-site.xml file:

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>local</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification/name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>file:///tmp/hive/warehouse</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>file:///tmp/hive</value>
</property>
```

Does this mean that I still need to have all of the hadoop binaries downloaded and have HADOOP_HOME set to that path? Or does local mode in hive allow me to run without needing all of that content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive doesn't require HDFS or YARN to execute, but it still requires the Hadoop input / output formats like Spark

Comment: Got it, thanks. The documentation on this is kinda sparse.

Comment: Requirements for install... *Hadoop 2.x (preferred)* ?